# C# List vs LinkedList vs Array

Tags: c#, массивы, list, c#-faq

`List` vs `LinkedList` vs `Array`

В каких случаях что лучше использовать?

C#-FAQ вопрос полезный для прохождения собеседований, а так же весьма полезен с теоретической точки зрения.

Comment: закрывать не нужно, несмотря на видимую очевидность, вопрос полезен, особенно новичкам. Довольно часто задают на собеседованиях, и какие только ответы на него не попадаются, в том числе от самих спрашивающих, так что качественный ответ будет весьма кстати.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Я сделал некоторые тесты. Думаю, многим будет интересно посмотреть на результаты. Исходники тестов по линке:  https://github.com/ukushu/DataStructuresTests.git

---

**Короткие выводы:**

- Array нужно использовать:

  - Максимально часто, если это возможно (быстродействие и оптимальность памяти)
  - Если не нужно добавлять ячейки
  - Если ожидаемый вес < 85000b
  - Если нужна Random Access Speed
- List нужно использовать:

  - Если нужно добавлять ячейки в конец списка (в большом/малом количестве)
  - Если нужно добавлять ячейки в начало/середину списка (в **малом** количестве)
  - Если ожидаемый вес < 85000b
  - Если нужна Random Access Speed
  - Предпочтительно инициализировать с уже набранным количеством элементов, если это возможно.
- LinkedList

  - Если нужно добавлять ячейки в начало/середину/конец листа в большом количестве
  - Если нужен только последовательный доступ (не нужны индексы для random access)
  - Хорошо подходит для хранения увесистых обьектов в относительно небольшом количестве т.к. под каждую ячейку так же нужно выделять память на 2 ссылки.

---

**Детальные выводы:**

- светлокрасный фон -- плохой результат.
- желтый фон -- нормальный(средний) результат.
- светлозеленый фон -- хороший результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**И немного информации, которую просто интересно узнать:**

1. LinkedList внутри вообще не является List в языках .NET. `LinkedList<T>`. Он даже не реализован на `IList<T>`. Вот почему там нет индексов и методов, которые связаны с индексами.
2. `LinkedList<T>` - это node-pointer based collection. В .NET это реализовано в doubly linked implementation, то есть каждый элемент ссылается на предыдущий и последующий за ним. А так же то, что данные будут фрагментированы. Разные объекты в листе будут находится в разных местах оперативной памяти. Так же это значит, что будет использовано больше памяти под `LinkedList<T>` чем под `List<T>` или `Array`, как и видно из тестов.
3. `Array<T>` как и `List<T>` (в .Net - это враппер вокруг Аrray с возможностью изменения размера) резервируют память оперативки как один продолжительный блок. Если общий размер элементов размер > 85000 bytes, он будет переразмещен в Large Object Heap. Что в свою очередь может привести к heap fragmentation -- что-то вроде легкой формы memory leak.
4. `List<T>` в памяти будет занимать значительно меньше памяти, если его создавать не пустым, а приблизительно наперед нужного размера. То есть, если вы ожидаете что в листе должно быть 1000 ячеек, то он будет занимать как массив данных с 1000 ячеек. Если же вы его создали пустым и заполнили до количества в 1000 ячеек, он будет занимать больше, как показано в тестах.

> ВАЖНО
>   Если кто нашел ошибки -- укажите пожалуста в коментариях. Независимо
>   от того, ошибки в коде, или в моих тестах, или моих выводах. :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55491/discussion-between-andrew-and-pashapash).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55658/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-c-list-vs-linkedlist-vs-array).

Comment: @NickVolynkin раз вы снесли развернутый отзыв до того, как топикастер исправил ответ - оставлю краткий: большая часть тестов не меряют ничего (или не то, что предполагалось), т.к. составлены с ошибками, бенчмарк топикастер запускал в дебаге, результаты не имеют ничего общего с реальной производительностью.

Comment: @PashaPash я его в чат переместил, но могу восстановить.

Comment: Я и вправду не учел разницы в релизе и дебаге. Я в ближайшее время обновлю результаты(пара дней). Там отдельно будут результаты с дебага и отдельно с релиза. Так же тесты нужно актуализировать под релиз, а то оптимизатор майкрсофта часть тестов ломает. Пока что возможности подправить все что нужно не было. Краткие выводы остаются теми же. Детальние выводы практически не изменятся, а цыфры деталей тестов изменятся довольно сильно.

Comment: @Andrew, стоит добавить разнообразия в тесты, например не только для массивов `int`, но и объектов, и каких-нибудь своих структур.

Comment: @Grundy Если чесно, я и так задолбался :D

Comment: @Andrew, а кто говорил, что будет легко? :)