# Самая легковесная коллекция .NET

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции, производительность

Скажем, требуется передать IEnumerable в метод. У нас имеется от 2 до 10 элементов. Какой класс коллекции был бы наиболее уместен и удачен в плане производительности, если после передачи коллекции в метод нам больше не потребуется эта коллекция (то есть функционала IEnumerable для нее вполне достаточно)? Вот примерное применение нужной коллекции:

```
Task.WhenAll(new List<Task> { SomeTask1, SomeTask2, SomeTask3 });
```

Дополнение:
Много интересных вариантов и предложений, спасибо всем)

Comment: Даже более чем какая-нибудь производная от ValueType?

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: Легковесная для чего? Для перечисления? Для выделения/освобождения памяти? Хотелось бы больше информации о требованиях к коллекции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я выше написал для чего. Внутри метода, в который передается IEnumerable коллекцию будут только перечислять, очевидно. Более ни для чего, разве что можно учесть, что она передается в качестве аргумента, тоже важно.

Comment: Галочку можно поставить только на один ответ, который вы считаете наиболее полезным.

Comment: @aepot я так и сделал, просто передумал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В шарпе и List и массив одинаково легковесны.
Но с одним уточнением - если лист создавался с предустановленным количеством элементов. Это связано с тем, что в шарпе List является ArrayList - то есть враппером вокруг массива. И если ты задаешь наперед количество элементов - они, фактически, идентичны между собой по легковесности.

[C# List vs LinkedList vs Array](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639301/c-list-vs-linkedlist-vs-array/639302#639302)

Comment: Не помню где слышал, что если работать с базой, то в .core более выигрышно использовать .ToList чем .ToArray, в старых версиях .net - наоборот. Помнится, это рассказывал какой-то докладчик, видео на ютубе, надо будет поискать пруф.

Comment: Вполне возможно, хоть и звучит странно. Но здесь в задаче .toList/toArray не используется. Но информация интересная, не сталкивался раньше с ней.

Comment: @AK все зависит от конкретной реализации ToList / ToArray в конкретном Linq провайдере.

Answer (score 7):

Можно вот так `Task.WhenAll(SomeTask1, SomeTask2, SomeTask3)`. А вообще самая легковесная коллекция - это массив, то есть `new Task[]`.

В .NET Core появилась еще одна [штука](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netcore-3.1) - `ArrayPool<T>`. Ее можно не только с `Task` использовать, а вообще с чем угодно. Единственная проблема - вы должны заранее знать минимальный требуемый объем выделяемого вам массива.

```cs
ArrayPool<Task> pool = ArrayPool<Task>.Shared;
Task[] tasks = pool.Rent(3);
tasks[0] = ...;
await Tasks.WhenAll(tasks[..3]);
pool.Return(tasks);
```

В этом случае аллокация массива произойдет только один раз, и далее он будет переиспользоваться. В общем, быстрее дальше некуда.

*Но там есть тонкости, пул дает вам массив длиной больше либо равной той, которую вы запросили. Так что конкретно с тасками его может быть и не очень удобно будет использовать, но здесь надо смотреть на то, как себя будет вести `Task.WhenAll` с недозаполненным массивом, я не проверял. Поэтому я в коде [использую](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.1) `System.Range` - `tasks[..3]`.*

**Бонус**

Еще один вариант (правда не в тему) - это аллокация массива в стеке, такой фокус позволяет провернуть в .NET Core `Span<T>`. Но с `Task` это работать не будет, а будет работать только с неуправляемыми типами - примитивами. И так же, этот фокус нельзя вытворять в асинхронных методах. Так же такой способ быстрой аллокации не подходит для больших массивов, 1 МБ стека (по умолчанию) может легко переполниться, что будет дальше - вы знаете.

```cs
Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[100]; // аллокация в стеке - очень быстро
```

```cs
Span<byte> span = new byte[100]; // обычная аллокация в куче
```

Подробнее можно прочитать в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/memory-t-usage-guidelines).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118960/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot----net).

Answer (score 5):

Всё же напишу ещё один ответ.

Метод `Task.WhenAll` имеет перегрузки с ключевым словом `params`. Что позволяет использовать его так:

```
Task.WhenAll(SomeTask1, SomeTask2, SomeTask3)
```

То есть не нужно явно создавать коллекцию. Массив будет создан автоматически.

Удобно? Да. Перечисление массива эффективно? Несомненно.

---

Однако, некоторые статические анализаторы на такой код выдают предупреждение об `array allocation` - выделении памяти под массив.

Если этот код будет использован однократно, то можно так и оставить.

Но если он будет вызываться многократно, а ваше приложения является высоконагруженным, то следует избавиться от лишней аллокации.
Как раз для этого в новых версиях языка и придуманы `ArrayPool` и `Span` + `stackalloc`. С кожалению, пул выдаст массив с размером 16 элементов. А у `WhenAll` нет перегрузки, принимающей спан.

Вероятно, проще всего будет создать поле для нашего массива:

```
private Task[] tasks = new Task[3]; // это именно ПОЛЕ класса, а не локальная переменная!
```

В методе заполняем его и используем:

```
tasks[0] = SomeTask1;
tasks[1] = SomeTask2;
tasks[2] = SomeTask3;

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

В итоге получаем единственную аллокацию на все вызовы.
Но это пригодно если только количество элементов не меняется от вызова к вызову.

Comment: Вот, да, тоже вариант - создать массив за пределами цикла или метода.

Comment: @aepot - Точно! Добавил `private`

Comment: Только с многопоточностью аккуратнее: если два потока одновременно возьмут один массив для заполнения и передачи в `Task.WhenAll` - получится ерунда.

Comment: @PavelMayorov верно, это еще один повод таки [юзать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53273365/12888024) `ArrayPool`. :)

Comment: Хороший вариант, но честно говоря пример с WhenAll был чисто случаен. Я мог бы написать: SomeMethod(IEnumerable<T> items){...} и в него уже передавать

Comment: @Олег вы знакомы с `yield return` и как энумераторы реализуются? Если нет, копать еще можно туда.