# Однозначная разница между коллекциями, массивами и дженериками, и их внутреннее устройство C#

Tags: c#

Запутался в коллекциях, нужны кратко ключевые моменты по всем коллекциям.

Можно ли назвать массив - коллекцией? Здравый смысл говорит да, ибо это коллекция элементов, но в шарпе есть массивы, есть коллекции, и есть дженерики. И не все с ними понятно.

1. Мы знаем, что коллекции - это старый вариант универсальных механизмов группировок элементов, которые были ДО дженериков
   Это ArrayList, Stack, Queue, Hashtable

Все что ты туда добавляешь, сохраняется как `object`, из-за чего происходит упаковка-распаковка, и если переменная была типа значения, например int, то мы её копируем - и получаем в результате две переменных.

Вопрос - это работает только в коллекциях, или простой массив работает таким же образом?

Происходит ли в массиве int упаковка-распаковка при присвоении значения ячейки?
Копируем ли мы значение int при присвоении значения ячейки массива, или это работает как то иначе?

2. В Рихтере написано, что одно из преимуществ дженериков является отсутствие упаковки - распаковки,
   т.к. дженерики строго типизированные и не преобразуются в объект и обратно, так и храняться.

Но они ведь храняться в куче? И всё равно мы имеем копирование значений, если исходный тип - тип значения?

3. Верно ли, что абсолютно для всех коллекций ссылочные типы работают одинаково - не копируются и просто хранят в своих ячейках ссылки на экземпляры? Основная разница в массивах, коллекциях и дженериках проявляется именно при обращении с типом значения?
4. Все коллекции и массивы - ссылочные типы, и все их ячейки со всем их содержимым хранятся в куче?
5. Что под капотом у коллекций? Как внутри реализован например ArrayList или List?
   Прочитал что у Dictionary под капотом Hashtable, и он просто использует хеш ключа для поиска, а как работает сама Hashtable? Есть ли у неё внутри массив?

Вопросы пересекаются и немного запутаны, ибо я в них вложил все что знаю о коллекциях. Вроде и пользуюсь, но разрозненно все, и вот сейчас Рихтера прочитал и вообще запутался.

Если есть краткая выжимка о сравнении всех коллекций и их внутренней реализации в шарпе, буду благодарен.

Comment: слишком много вопросов на один вопрос. Это тянет на целый раздел из книги, как по мне. На часть из них знаю ответы но писать слишком много, нужно вопрос конкретизировать, как по мне. Могу только дать дополнительную пищу для ума в виде этого вопроса-ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639301/c-list-vs-linkedlist-vs-array/639302#639302

Comment: Коллекции и дженерики — это ортогональные вещи. Как устроены коллекции (или любые другие классы) внутри лучше посмотреть в исходниках — это самая достоверная информация

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic - обобщение.
Коллекции могут обобщённые и необобщённые.

Массивы изначально имели особый статус и, по сути, были обобщёнными всегда.

---

Вас, похоже, пугает копирование значений. Но этого не нужно бояться, потому что значимые типы принято делать маленькими и их копирование сравнимо с копированием указателей ссылочных типов.

Раз уж вы читали Рихтера, значит морально готовы к боли и унижению... В современных реализациях дотнета ссылочные типы могут создаваться на стеке! Но это оптимизация рантайма и нас особо волновать не должна.

---

Разница между обобщёнными и необобщёнными коллекциями проявляется не только при обращении с типом значения. С дженериками не нужен каст (приведение) из `object` при работе со ссылочными типами. То есть использовать их намного проще и безопаснее.

---

Приведу схему, как хранятся значимые типы в массивах и дженерик-коллекциях типа `List<T>`:

```
[value1|value2|value3]
```

А вот так они будут храниться в необобщённой коллекции:

```
[ref1|ref2|ref3]

ref1: box(value1)

ref2: box(value2)

ref3: box(value3)
```

В самой коллекции - ссылки. А упакованные (boxed) значения раскиданы по куче.

---

> 4. Все коллекции и массивы - ссылочные типы, и все их ячейки со всем их содержимым хранятся в куче?

Не обязательно. Вот, например, [ImmutableArray Struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-5.0) - как видите, это значимый тип. А что там внутри - неважно.

Никто и ничто не мешает создать структуру-коллекцию, хранящую набор значений в полях. Реализовать индексатор, энумератор - все атрибуты коллекции. При этом куча не используется.

[stackalloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) - стандартный способ создания массивов на стеке.

---

> 5. Что под капотом у коллекций?

Если смотреть на этот вопрос широко, в философском смысле, то ответ: что угодно!
Там может быть кусок памяти выделенной на стеке или в куче, а может быть и прямое обращение к файлу, базе данных или сервису по любому протоколу.

---

Про реализацию Hash table можете почитать в [Випипедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) (меня в своё время ошарашило её внутреннее устройство, сперва поразила сложность, а в итоге очаровала красота способа).

Там же ознакомьтесь с прочими [структурами данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Если владеете английским, переключитесь на него.

Answer (score 0):

Вот частичный ответ.

Технически в C# массивы не являются коллекциями, потому что они не являются частью System.Collections.
Здравый смысл, как вы написали, заставляет нас думать о массивах и коллекциях в целом как о структурах данных, содержащих наборы значений. Подобно тому, что в математике мы называем «множествами».
Главное, у массивов нет проблем с упаковкой / распаковкой.

Мы знаем, что коллекции составляют основу ряда структур, используемых для хранения данных в C #.
Эти коллекции являются специализированными или расширенными для обеспечения некоторых дополнительных функций - например, стека, очереди, словаря, хеш-таблицы.

В исходных версиях без дженериков используется object. А для типов значений подразумевают использование механизма упаковки / распаковки.
Проверить эту статью: "Non-generic collections shouldn't be used" https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0006.md

Дженерики - это не только особенность коллекции. Они важной особенностью C#.
Для коллекций они дают возможность хранить значение, не упаковывая его как object.

Больше информации - вероятно, слишком много - здесь: https://mihai-albert.com/2020/02/10/boxing-performance-in-c-versus-generics/