# Что такое интрузивный список и как он хранит данные?

Tags: c#, .net, структуры-данных, терминология

Что это за структура данных и как работает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интрузивный список - это список в котором элемент хранит свои полезные данные и связи с другими элементами вместе.

```
struct list_item {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      list_item *next;
}
```

В неинтрузивном списке тип с полезными данными помещается внутрь типа элемента списка.

```
struct my_type {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
}
struct list_item {
      my_type *data;
      list_item *next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В обычном `List<Struct>` данные находятся последовательно. В ячейках сохраняются значимые типы данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же это `List<Class>`  то все сложнее но суть +- та же.

Т.к. один и тот же тип данных занимает одинаковое количество места - мы можем передвигаться по массиву или листу сдвигом памяти. То есть как бы отступать на определенное количество байт дальше и получать значение хранящееся в ячейке.

---

> Интрузивный список — это такой список, в котором каждый элемент
> содержит ссылки на соседей. Другими словами, элементы в таком списке
> «имеют представление» о том, что находятся в списке и своем положении
> в нем, тогда как в обычном списке данные и информация о соседних
> элементах изолированы друг от друга.

Но есть и иной подход - он используется в LinkedList - это когда тип данных сохраняемый в листе помещается в обертку. Обертка в себе имеет сам обьект и две ссылки на соседние ячейки - предыдущую и последующую.

Это и есть пример Интрузивного списка.

Обращаться по индексу там невозможно.

Если ты стоишь перед диллемой: "стоит ли использовать LinkedList или нет?" - его НЕ СТОИТ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ.

LinkedList стоит использовать:

- Если нужно добавлять ячейки в начало/середину/конец листа в большом количестве
- Если нужен только последовательный доступ (не нужны индексы для random access)
- Хорошо подходит для хранения увесистых обьектов в относительно небольшом количестве т.к. под каждую ячейку так же нужно выделять память на 2 ссылки.

---

Смежная полезная информация по этой теме: [C# List vs LinkedList vs Array](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639301/186752)

Comment: Это обычный связный список, а есть интрузивный где контейнер полностью встроенный в свои елементы.

Comment: @Illusion интрузивный список сравнивают с очередью в поликлинике. Линкед лист по-факту очень близок к этому - каждый элемент знает о соседних элементах (о прошлом человеке в очереди и о следующем элементе - благодаря линкам во враппере). Если я ошибаюсь и линкедЛист не является интрузивным - то какой из списов тогда является представителем интрузивного списка?)

Comment: Наподобии такого: public ref readonly struct Car {
  public ref Car _next;
  public int Speed;
}

Comment: Когда наш елемент по факту и является контейнером, и не надо выделять ни единого байта памяти на доп структуру

Comment: Ну уж нет, `LinkedList<T>` не интрузивный.

Comment: @Illusion если вы и сами всё знаете, зачем вопрос задавали?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - я, видимо, ошибся, назвав LinkedList интрузивным списком. Выше пишут, что "Линкед лист по-факту очень близок к этому". а нельзя ли написать, почему, все таки, LinkedList не является интрузивным списком? Хотелось бы разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov когда задавал вопрос не знал, щас знаю)

Comment: @Illusion так напишите ответ тогда